# keytool is not recognized as internal or external command flutter android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Whenever I try to run this command`keytool -genkey -v -keystore flutter_release_apk.jks -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 20000`

I get below error

> C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\eat_healthy\flutter_tes>keytool -genkey -v -keystore flutter_release_apk.jks -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 20000
>   'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Please help if you have any solution

Comment: Go to this path or where ever you have your keytool.exe file
e.g C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin   check there is file exist or not?

Comment: @NeerajAmoli    I went there but there is no JRE . I am using jdk13

Comment: there also  keytool.exe

Comment: you should registered jdk/bin path to environment variable, and then you will be able to use keytool.

Comment: I have already registered.But I don't have any JRE. I hv only installed  JDK  no JRE

Comment: But there is file named keytool inside bin folder of jdk

Comment: open command prompt here and then run keytool command, if it work , you have to cross check your system variable, e.g JAVA_HOME,PATH

Comment: i tried to open it but command prompt opens for a millisecond then disappears

Comment: ok , please run keytool command with fully relative path like c://..../bin/keytool  from  cmd and check output.

Comment: C:\Users\user>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\bin\keytool
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program  

C:\Users\user>C://ProgramFiles/Java/jdk-13/bin/keytool
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\user>C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-13\bin\keytool
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\user>C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-13\bin
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\user>C://ProgramFiles/Java/jdk-13/bin/
'C://ProgramFiles/Java/jdk-13/bin/' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program